# Python: How to invert a binary string without using loops in Python?

Tags: python, string, binary

I'm working on a project where I need to invert binary strings (i.e., change 0s to 1s and 1s to 0s). For example, if the input is "0110010", the output should be "1001101".

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use Python loops (like for or while) for performance reasons. I've tried using a list comprehension, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
s = "0110010"
s = "".join('1' if bit == '0' else '0' for bit in s)
print(s)
```

Is there a more efficient way to solve this problem in Python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920494/python-flipping-binary-1s-and-0s-in-a-string   there is an answer a few down the page using maketrans.

Comment: Why do you even have a billion-character string of ones and zeros?

Comment: this is a task.

Comment: and why people dont like this question?

Comment: What do you think it means to not use a loop?

Comment: "''.join('1' if i == '0' else '0' for i in x) to not use such things

Comment: I think the question could be better described. Anyway I found it a bit challenging because of the string size and the requirement of no loop. Do you mean no explicit loop or no loop at all?

Comment: i need a code with high speed

Comment: Please, so edit your question, be precise

Comment: thank you, but people already had answered to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How to do this with either strings *or* binary literals.

Easy, use a bitwise operator. This is the proper way to do it, because it's useful to understand how to use these operators in Python. If this is a task, this seems like the way whoever set the task wanted it to be done.

```
# Make binary literal (0b prefix)
b = 0b11001001
# And use the complement operator
print(~b)

#Or if you want to print out the binary, try
print(bin(~b))
```

Here are some examples:

```
>>> ~0b110011
-52
>>> bin(~0b110001)
'-0b110010'
>>> bin(~0b11000)
'-0b11001'
```

If your binary number is a string:

```
s = "101"
# bin(~int(s,2)) = "010"
```

**Note**, you might want to trim the first three characters off of the space if you want *just* the binary characters, e.g.

```
bin(~int(s,2))[3:]
```

Comment: but i have strings, could you show ways how to convert string to bin , and bin to string?

Answer (score 4):

The simple way by use swapping:

```
st = "0110010"
st=st.replace("0","a")
st=st.replace("1","0")
st=st.replace("a","1")
print (st)
```

Comment: This is useful, but it requires 3 loops through the string. This can be done in one loop using the the comprehension idea I posted in a separate answer.

Comment: @RobertB: The comprehension is a Python-level loop, though, so it has a lot more overhead than the C-level loop inside `replace`. The comprehension doesn't actually win the timing.

Comment: Nice. Intuition proved me wrong... dang interpreter ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
''.join('1' if x == '0' else '0' for x in '0110010')
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code works with strings, try it:

```
>>> from string import maketrans
>>>
>>> initial_string = "10101010100011010"
>>> converted_string = initial_string.translate(maketrans("10","01"))

>>> converted_string    # The result is
'01010101011100101'
>>>
```