# How do I bit flip binary numbers in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
third_number = int(input('Enter a Number: '), 2)
bitwise_NOT = ~third_number
bitwise_NOT = f'{bitwise_NOT:01b}'
print(bitwise_NOT[0:])
```

I need to interchange binary bits and print out 1's compliment but for some reason it shows wrong values.

```
Inputs         outputs
10110101010       0110101011
011               00
10001             0010
1111111           0000000
0000              [no output]
111000011         11000100
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920494/python-flipping-binary-1s-and-0s-in-a-string

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please share a bit more details and explain your code. It is not clear, whether this is your desired or actual output

Comment: As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Take a look over [Here](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/challenges/1/python-challenges-1-exercise-18.php).

Comment: The documentation for the Python standard library says the following about bitwise operations on integer types: *The result of bitwise operations is calculated as though carried out in two’s complement with an infinite number of sign bits.* I think you are expecting one's complement. To do what you want it might be easier to accept the number as a string and replace the `0`s with `1`s and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Python `int` with base 10 do not allow for leading 0's. `num = 01` for example will not work. If you're okay with representing your binary string as actual strings, you could do it like this.

```
def binaryFlip(bitstring: str):
    res = ""
    for bit in bitstring:
        invertedBit = "0" if bit == "1" else "1"
        res += (invertedBit)
    return res
```

You could also represent your binary string as lists, if you so choose. As lists, you could approach it like this:

```
def binaryFlip(bitstring: list):
    res = []
    for bit in bitstring:
        res.append(1 - bit)
    return res
```